# How to prevent and safeguard yourself from getting negatively affected by the behaviour of someone at the office

Tags: ethics, unprofessional-behavior, employer-relations, conflict, behavior

I was recruited to a workplace to do things in subject A. At the interview also they discussed in that way. But now all of a sudden, my Manager asked me whether I can do things in subject B.

I'm not exactly fluent in subject B, so I explained it and said I'll do it well as possible to my capacity. She all of a sudden started to criticize me and said perhaps my extension of the contract will not be continued.

She and I both do the things in subject A, and during working together I've sometimes felt as if she is feeling envious or grudging towards me. My expertise in the subject is higher than hers. She had gossiped with some juniors related to the work and has done something like driving them against me to appreciate only her, through those gossip and implications. Some I overheard, without her knowing, but I don't know what exactly this behaviour is called (*).

However, I have knowledge in a subject C, and I've actually informed the previous Manager that I can do it. But they have recruited a new person to do it, the previous Manager was a bit sloppy, must have forgotten about me.

Before the new person came, actually I said the current Manager, that I've informed about my abilities in subject C, I'll do it if you haven't still taken a new person for that, then you can take a new one for subject B. But by then they told me that already the new person was recruited.

What the Manager did was, in addition to saying that my contract is at risk because the company requires a person who knows both A and C (she says now that they want both A and C, didn't say when interviewing me), she has said the new person that her job is also at risk because they might want to keep me and make her leave, due to the limited number of vacancies available.

This made the new person turn kind of against me, like in above (*) case. I'm a bit sort of a patient person. Else, things would have turned me against the new one too, wishing her to leave. But what I felt was pathetic and sad that someone else's job is also getting threatened now by putting the blame on me. I mean, after the new one is recruited, asking her to leave is bad, but they could have considered my subjects beforehand.

There was also another subject I could help with by collaborating with another person in another division and save all of our employments, but she doesn't agree. I've expressed many more several solutions to cover subject B, she doesn't consider them either.

And now after making me feel bad this way, she has planned now to keep all of us. There had not been such a serious problem with the vacancies. But still the Manager is not telling me the truth. I've found out via someone who goes to their senior meetings, who is friendly with me.

So, what type of behaviour is this? How should I protect myself from getting subjected to such behaviour and also prevent other co-workers and juniors from turning against me, based on what she says? Is this a common type of human behaviour? How can I understand?

None of my friends are like this.

Sometimes, I don't understand what's going on. Looks like, I have to live my life according to the plans she make?

Please advise.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It sounds like someone isn't communicating well. I can't tell whether it's you, your manager, or your manager's manager.

Comment: Thank you. Why do you think it might be me? Not communicating well means exactly in what way do you mean? @keshlam I feel that they doing some kind of a biased activity against me. The Manager's Manager: Chairman is also biased I think. And they want me to leave on my own perhaps?

Comment: I mean, by the way a person is speaking also, sometimes we get the feeling that they are lying or deceiving us sometimes. When this Manager started to trouble me to this extent, I felt as if she is doing it for lies and Chairwoman also go involved with her to play it, because my observations in the past has given me the idea that they like to make fun of other people's misery and feel themselves higher if possible..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a choice to make. Do you want to be the helpless victim or do you want to take action yourself and determine yourself how your life looks like?

Why are you still there?

They told you, your job is not safe there.

There is only two options, either it is the innocent truth, or it's even worse.

Go find a job that is safe. Like yesterday!

Comment: Thanks a lot @nvoigt I want to know also, that what if someone there also start to behave like this? Is there a way to prevent someone acting like this from the beginning itself, I mean soon as you enter a new company, by the way you speak or maintain interactions etc? What things I should focus on to prevent such actions happening to me in the future. What they did was creating a fake situation. After seeing this, I feel that then anyone can make any situation like this in a fake way right?

Comment: I'm actually happy to leave after the way she spoke to me. I am actually a friend of a friend of that Manager and Chairwoman, but still this is how they treated me. I also want to explain this to my friend, partly because he has some contacts which might help me to find a new job. But since he is also friends with those women, he is going to find it hard to believe what happened when I tell at once, and he might suspect that there might be faults on both sides and might start questioning them too.

Comment: When anyone asks anyway, they put on a good show, and hence they are going to tell lies to cover up what happened, and then I'm going to be trapped. What is the best way to express the situation to my friend safely? Above I have explained all the actions happened, but it's difficult to explain like that to my busy friend. Are there any specific words/phrases I can simply due to describe the Manager's behaviour and situations she is creating? How can I express she made others to have conflicts with me too @nvoigt please be kind enough to tell me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a word we can use to specify the behaviour (*)? @nvoigt the company is not going to make any of us leave now apparently, that's what I've got to know as inside information from another person. But I don't understand why she played like that with me.

Comment: This isn't a discussion site. If you have additional questions, post new Questions.  Assuming they're good questions; if you just want opinions they're likely to be closed. We can't answer why anyone else does anything, or whether they did anything.

Comment: @keshlam thanks a lot. If possible please kindly let me know only, why you've felt that there can be a communication issue with me even? I'm hoping to tell this to some other people too, I'd like to modify my way of explaining to be more clear

Comment: Clearer: Delete most of the backstory. Focus on situation now. Don't bury the lede. (And with that, I'm out.)

Comment: @Mary you can't control what another person does. You can only control your own actions. Situations change. Trying to make a situation the way you want it is a fast way into being emotionally controlled by others. Accept that the situation exists and make your own decisions about staying in it.

Comment: Okay thank you very much @keshlam

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidR

Comment: @DavidR but I also would like to know why it was felt as if I'm trying to make the situation as I want? I'm trying to figure out to protect myself isn't it? Please kindly tell me

Comment: @Mary, if you feel that you need to protect yourself, then you are in a dangerous situation. The best way to protect is to leave. Anything keeping you in that job can be used to manipulate you.

Comment: Thank you @DavidR yes, I've told my resignation now. It is going to be a one month notice, so I've to stay a bit more. Pretty sickening it is.